# How to mix *args, **kwargs and named arguments in decorator

Tags: python, arguments, decorator

I want to create a custom decorator, called `captain_hook`. It should store `hooks` - functions to be called before the decorated function - and call them:

```
def captain_hook(func):
    def closure(hooks=[], *args, **kwargs):
        for hook in hooks: 
            hook(*args, **kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return closure
```

Now I could say:

```
@captain_hook
def sum(a, b):
    return a+b
sum.__defaults__[0].append(lambda arg: sys.stdout.write(str(arg))) #this lambda function prints argument
sum(1, 2) #should write (1, 2) and return 3
```

The problem is that I can't pass the arguments to `closure`, cause first element of `args` mistakingly unpacks to `hooks` argument: `sum(1, 2)` sets `hook=1`, `a=2`, `b - undefined`. How do I do that?

Comment: When do you intend to pass the hooks?  The way you have it set up, you don't specify any hooks when you use `captain_hook`, and you also don't give any when you call `sum`, so there are no hooks involved.  Do you want to specify the hooks when the function is defined or when it's called?

Comment: @BrenBarn I edited question. I'll install hooks before I call the function. When I create new object, that is going to be affected by call of the function and should adapt to changes, it's hook will be called. The hook is installed by changing `sum.__defaults__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying `__defaults__` is a very dubious way to handle this.  `__defaults__` is for argument default values.  If your hooks aren't going to be passed as arguments, you shouldn't store them as an argument default value.

If you really want to be able to modify the hooks later on, you should make your decorator a class that stores the hooks on itself.  Here's an example:

```
class CaptainHook(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.hooks = []
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for hook in self.hooks:
            hook(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then:

```
>>> @CaptainHook
... def sum(a, b):
...     return a+b
>>> sum(1, 2)
3
>>> def aHook(*args, **kwargs):
...     print "I am a hook!"
>>> sum.hooks.append(aHook)
>>> sum(1, 2)
I am a hook!
3
```

Comment: Just as I thought of that, you've written it. Thanks for a good sample, your approach is much better, mine was too hacky.